# Terraform - list of string required (cidr_blocks in AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, iaas

In Terraform I'm having problems inputting a list that will be stored in a variable.

While executing `terraform plan`, I get asked for a cidr_blocks (which should be a list of strings).

I tried to type several "forms" that might represent a list of strings but always get an error.

Examples:

1st attempt:

```
$terraform plan
...
var.monitoring_access_ips_mysystem
  Enter a value: "10.180.1.0/24", "10.180.2.0/25", "10.180.3.0/23"
```

2nd attempt:

```
var.monitoring_access_ips_mysystem
  Enter a value: ["10.180.1.0/24", "10.180.2.0/25", "10.180.3.0/23"]
```

3rd attempt:

```
var.monitoring_access_ips_mysystem
  Enter a value: '["10.180.1.0/24", "10.180.2.0/25", "10.180.3.0/23"]'
```

4th attempt:

```
var.monitoring_access_ips_mysystem
  Enter a value: "["10.180.1.0/24", "10.180.2.0/25", "10.180.3.0/23"]"
```

5th attempt:

```
var.monitoring_access_ips_mysystem
  Enter a value: "10.180.1.0/24"
```

For any attempt, the error is always the same:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ecs/security_group.tf line 10, in resource "aws_security_group" "ecs-cluster-sg":
  10:     cidr_blocks = var.monitoring_access_ips_mysystem

Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": list of string required.
```

And the `ecs/security_group.tf` file looks like this
**ecs/security_group.tf:**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ecs-cluster-sg" {
  name   = "${var.app_name}-cluster-sg"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    description = "Ingress from monitoring VPC on custom port"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = var.monitoring_access_ips_mysystem
  }
  ...
```

What valid format can I type/pass the IPs so that it is accepted as a 'list of strings'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UI input (what you see when you are prompted after running a Terraform command without some variables defined) [only supports string values](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/variables.html) so if you want to pass something that isn't a string then you will need to do so non interactively. This can be one of any of the listed options in the [variables documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables). These are:

> - In a Terraform Cloud workspace.
> - Individually, with the -var command line option.
> - In variable definitions (.tfvars) files, either specified on the    command line or automatically loaded.
> - As environment variables.

In your case you could run a plan with the following command:

```sh
terraform plan -var='monitoring_access_ips_mysystem=["10.180.1.0/24", "10.180.2.0/25", "10.180.3.0/23"]'
```

Unless this is something that is likely to change on each run of Terraform then normally that should instead be put in a `terraform.tfvars` file like this:

```
monitoring_access_ips_mysystem = [
  "10.180.1.0/24",
  "10.180.2.0/25",
  "10.180.3.0/23",
]
```